# Why Do Textures Appear Black In OpenGL 4.5 In Windows?

Tags: opengl, windows

I usually code in Linux, and when I ran my OpenGL program the textures displayed correctly. However, when I ran it on Windows the textures appeared black until I used old OpenGL for the textures. Is there anything wrong in the code that creates the texture?

```
        int[] pixels = null;
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + path));
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
        pixels = new int[width * height];
        image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int[] data = new int[width * height];
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        int a = (pixels[i] & 0xff000000) >> 24;
        int r = (pixels[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
        int g = (pixels[i] & 0xff00) >> 8;
        int b = (pixels[i] & 0xff);

        data[i] = a << 24 | b << 16 | g << 8 | r;
    }

    textureID = GL45.glCreateTextures(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL45.glBindTextureUnit(0, textureID);
    GL45.glTextureStorage2D(textureID, 1, GL11.GL_RGBA, width, height);
    GL45.glTextureParameteri(textureID, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    GL45.glTextureParameteri(textureID, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    GL45.glTextureSubImage2D(textureID, 0, width, 0, 0, height, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    GL45.glBindTextureUnit(0, 0);
```

EDIT: The answer was very simple. I had forgotten to do GL11.GL_RGBA8 instead of just GL11.GL_RGBA when doing GL45.glTextureStorage2D. This threw a GL_INVALID_ENUM error which caused glTextureSubImage to not store anything, causing the texture to be black. It was strange that this problem did not occur on Linux, though.

I will leave this problem open, as some commenters have pointed out that there is something majorly wrong with how I use the new DSA features.

Comment: OS is irrelevant. What's your hardware?

Comment: Also - why are you using DSA *and* binding? That's not correct API usage and it reads as though you've converted a tutorial to DSA without really understanding either (particularly with the unbinding).

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the feedback! Can you explain how I can fix it?

Comment: First tell us what your hardware is, because this is probably a hardware or driver problem.  As I said, OS is not relevant; OpenGL is not an OS component so you really need to start giving us the information we need in order to answer this.

Comment: Hardware: 8GB DDR3-1600 RAM, 1TB WD Blue HDD, AMD A10-7870k, however a friend with an nVidia GTX 960 tested this code and it also had black textures.

Comment: Are the drivers updated? Check the available OpenGL version

Comment: I did. On both OpenGL 4.5 works after checking.